# Spring Security 4 how to handle expired sessions for anonymous users

Tags: spring, spring-security

I asked this question 5 months ago in two different posts, but unfortunately received no responses to either one. It was suggested to me that the posts were too long (too much detail), so I'm going to try to boil it down to the essentials.

As far as I can tell, under Spring Security all users are subject to the security configuration for expired sessions, whether they are an anonymousUser or an authenticated user (login or remember me).  IMO, an anonymousUser should be allowed to view public pages (`.antMatchers.permitAll()`) for as long as they want, but if they stay on a single page for more than the session expiration limit they will get an expired session error, same as a logged in user.

What is the best approach to preventing this session error for anonymous users?  The easiest is to remove security from public pages (`web.ignoring().antMatchers`...) but many SO posts seem to indicate that is not advisable. Beyond that it appears that your options include picking a point to insert a custom filter, extending an existing filter like `SessionManagementFilter`,  or extending one of the redirect strategies like `DefaultRedirectStrategy` or `SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy`.

I have to believe this is a common situation - nearly all websites have public pages - so I'm curious what the most common or best practice approach is to solving it.